# How can i add custom link for "Advanced Search" if return no results

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, advanced-search

I need to add custom link in **`Advanced Search`**. If no products return, my link will be shown.

workout : i am added to the link in advanced search coding page,but it's remain also products results, my need no products then will shown my link.

How can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app\design\frontend\rwd\enterprise\template\catalogsearch\result.phtml

```
if($this->getResultCount()) {
...
}else{ 
// put your link here
}
```

Comment: @ Ryan Permana : i need display my custom link for advanced search, is it okay what you mentioned.

Comment: @ Ryan : could you pls join chat : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58239/how-can-i-add-custom-link-for-advanced-search-if-return-no-results

Comment: @Rathinam can you show me some of your code ? and please highlight part that's not working